# How to get over OrgWideAddress in Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, email, code-coverage, org-wide-email

Is there any way to "skip" the lines or either create the data without using @SeeAllData=ture?

I didn't found a solution without using it.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Sirlegaru welcome to salesforce stack exchange. already answer is present for your question. Please check this Link : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/224877/how-do-i-create-test-data-for-an-org-wide-email-address

Comment: I use a Selector pattern with an injected test selector to return a mocked OrgWideEmailAddress SObject